# UIButton to load next webpage from array in a UIWebView

Tags: ios

I'm trying to have a button that makes an UIWebView load the next URL from an array.

What is the best way of doing this?

Any example code would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

Create the UIWebView the way you normally would.

Create an array like this:

```
self.youtubeVideos = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"http://localhost/screen.php?video=McHosr_98r0", 
                   @"http://localhost/plasma/screen.php?video=TY1lNAEzZP0", 
                   @"http://localhost/plasma/screen.php?video=Ml-rxMwcaf0",
                   @"http://localhost/plasma/screen.php?video=N70DLM8Az_8",

                   nil];
currentVideoIndex = 0;
```

Then create a button in interface builder and hook it up to this:

```
-(IBAction)gotoAddress:(id) sender {

[downloadSourceField resignFirstResponder];

downloadSourceField.text = [youtubeVideos objectAtIndex:currentVideoIndex];
currentVideoIndex++;
if (currentVideoIndex >= youtubeVideos.count) {
    currentVideoIndex = 0;
}


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[downloadSourceField text]];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
[downloadSourceField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

To go backwards through the array, use this:

```
downloadSourceField.text = [youtubeVideos objectAtIndex:currentVideoIndex];
currentVideoIndex--;
if (currentVideoIndex < 0) {    
    currentVideoIndex = youtubeVideos.count-1;  
}
}
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: Except your final block (going back) should set currentVideoIndex to youtubeVideos.count when < 0.